# Unexpected characters in image url in ajax response Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In My Codeigniter web application I'm using an ajax function to get some data from the database inorder to show it in the view.The data from database contains an image url and other fields.

My problem is that when I get the data in ajax success function, the image url looks like this:

```
<button id='product-1301' type='button' value=1301 class='blue' ><i><img src='assets\/uploads\/thumbs\/default.png'></button>
```

Since the url contains these characters `\` my view is not rendering properly. I tried using stripslash function to remove this. But didn't work. I didn't know where am going wrong.

**my ajax function**

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "index.php?module=pos&view=ajaxproducts1",
data: {category_id: cat_id, per_page: p_page},
dataType: "html",
success: function(data) {

var x= data;
alert(x);
if(data!=1)
{   
$('#proajax').empty();
var newPrs = $('<div></div>');
newPrs.html(data);
newPrs.appendTo("#proajax");                                        
//$('#gmail_loading').hide();
}
else
{                               
bootbox.alert('Product is Not Available in this Category!');
$('#gmail_loading').hide();
}
}
});
```

**Controller**

```
    function ajaxproducts1()
    {
    $mn;$data1;
    $img="assets/uploads/thumbs/default.png"; //this is my image path, when this comes in ajax success,\ character adds
    $img=str_replace('\"', '', $img);
    if($this->input->get('category_id')) { $category_id = $this->input->get('category_id'); }
    if($this->input->get('per_page')) { $per_page = $this->input->get('per_page'); }
    if($item = $this->pos_model->getProductsByCategory($category_id,$per_page))
    {
    foreach ($item as $i)
    {
    $button="<button id='product-".$i->id."' type='button' value=".$i->id." class='blue' ><i><img src='".$img."'><span><span>".$i->name;
    $mn=$mn.$button;
    }
    $data1=$mn;
    }
    else
    {
    $data1=1;
    }
    echo json_encode($data1);
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: you could try `decodeURIComponent()` or `decodeURI()` javascript functions

Comment: have you tried `realpath('');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was solved by using `jQuery.parseJSON` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  // use an array to gather up all the values
    // call encodeURIComponent() on the variables before adding them
    // join them all together and pass them as "data"
    var tempVars=['module=pos&view=ajaxproducts1'];
        tempVars.push('category_id='+encodeURIComponent( cat_id ));
        tempVars.push('userInfo='+encodeURIComponent( p_page ));
    var sendVars=tempVars.join('&');
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "index.php",
        data: sendVars,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {

            var x = data;
            alert(x);
            if (data != 1) {
                $('#proajax').empty();
                var newPrs = $('<div></div>');
                newPrs.html(data);
                newPrs.appendTo("#proajax");
                //$('#gmail_loading').hide();
            } else {
                bootbox.alert('Product is Not Available in this Category!');
                $('#gmail_loading').hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is this page viewable online?

Comment: No.. Its in my localhost